# Hierarchical Index Sort by Columns while preserving the original columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to simulate a Hirarical Index dataFrame as Follows:

```
>>> raw_data = ({'city': ['Delhi', 'Kanpur', 'Mumbai', 'Pune','Delhi', 'Kanpur', 'Mumbai', 'Pune'],
...                 'rank': ['1st', '2nd', '1st', '2nd','1st', '2nd', '1st', '2nd'],
...                 'name': ['Ramesh', 'Kirpal', 'Jungi', 'Sanju','Ramesh', 'Kirpal', 'Jungi', 'Sanju'],
...                 'score1': [10,15,20,25,10,15,20,25],
...                 'score2': [20,35,40,45,20,35,40,45]})
```

Below is what DataFrame looks like, So, datFrame is coming with default Indexing.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['city', 'rank', 'name', 'score1', 'score2'])
>>> df
     city rank    name  score1  score2
0   Delhi  1st  Ramesh      10      20
1  Kanpur  2nd  Kirpal      15      35
2  Mumbai  1st   Jungi      20      40
3    Pune  2nd   Sanju      25      45
4   Delhi  1st  Ramesh      10      20
5  Kanpur  2nd  Kirpal      15      35
6  Mumbai  1st   Jungi      20      40
7    Pune  2nd   Sanju      25      45
```

I want to use Hierarchical Index by choosing `'city', 'rank'` columns with `set.index` method while Keeping the Original columns intacted.

```
>>> df.set_index(['city', 'rank'], drop=False)
               city rank    name  score1  score2
city   rank
Delhi  1st    Delhi  1st  Ramesh      10      20
Kanpur 2nd   Kanpur  2nd  Kirpal      15      35
Mumbai 1st   Mumbai  1st   Jungi      20      40
Pune   2nd     Pune  2nd   Sanju      25      45
Delhi  1st    Delhi  1st  Ramesh      10      20
Kanpur 2nd   Kanpur  2nd  Kirpal      15      35
Mumbai 1st   Mumbai  1st   Jungi      20      40
Pune   2nd     Pune  2nd   Sanju      25      45
```

But i'm looking to have Index by `city` First and then Index by `rank` :

```
               city rank    name  score1  score2
city   rank
Delhi  1st    Delhi  1st  Ramesh      10      20
       1st    Delhi  1st  Ramesh      10      20

Kanpur 2nd   Kanpur  2nd  Kirpal      15      35
       2nd   Kanpur  2nd  Kirpal      15      35

Mumbai 1st   Mumbai  1st   Jungi      20      40
       1st   Mumbai  1st   Jungi      20      40

Pune   2nd     Pune  2nd   Sanju      25      45
       2nd     Pune  2nd   Sanju      25      45
```

Comment: You need to sort the data by city, df.sort_values('city').set_index(['city', 'rank'], drop=False)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, you just need to apply `sort_index()`:

```
df.set_index(['city','rank'], drop=False).sort_index()
```

Yields:

```
               city rank    name  score1  score2
city   rank                                     
Delhi  1st    Delhi  1st  Ramesh      10      20
       1st    Delhi  1st  Ramesh      10      20
Kanpur 2nd   Kanpur  2nd  Kirpal      15      35
       2nd   Kanpur  2nd  Kirpal      15      35
Mumbai 1st   Mumbai  1st   Jungi      20      40
       1st   Mumbai  1st   Jungi      20      40
Pune   2nd     Pune  2nd   Sanju      25      45
       2nd     Pune  2nd   Sanju      25      45
```

And to remove duplicate rows, add `drop_duplicates()`:

```
df.set_index(['city','rank'], drop=False).sort_index().drop_duplicates()
```

Yields:

```
               city rank    name  score1  score2
city   rank                                     
Delhi  1st    Delhi  1st  Ramesh      10      20
Kanpur 2nd   Kanpur  2nd  Kirpal      15      35
Mumbai 1st   Mumbai  1st   Jungi      20      40
Pune   2nd     Pune  2nd   Sanju      25      45
```